# Child Project not able to use Parent spring boot project intellij

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to implement a base project in spring boot and will be added as dependency in multiple microservices. The base project will contains like model classes, utility class, generic response classes etc, will be imported in multiple spring boot microservices because the same entity, pojo, model,utility classes needed in multiple spring boot application. My first question is, is this a good practice to add a base project dependency in microservice or services should be standalone whether the code is redundant?

The base project jar installed in .m2 directory and have added dependency too in project but the import is not working in intellij

Already tried to reload project, invalid cache

**Base project pom**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project.alpha</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-alpha</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project-alpha</name>
    <description>Base Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Base project class**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseHeader {

    private boolean success;
    private String responseDescription;
    private ErrorResponse errorResponse;
}
```

**Child project pom**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.community</groupId>
    <artifactId>message-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>message-service</name>
    <description>Message Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project.alpha</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-alpha</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### First Question

- Is this a good practice to add a base project dependency in microservice or services should be standalone whether the code is redundant?

Actually it is  . In general ,in  Distributed service  its often provide a `api jar`    which contains `entity`, `vo`,`dto`  or `http` ,`rpc`  api as
base project that may be referred by other service a;

##### Second Question

- Installed dependency is invaild in maven

first of all , make sure that  maven  had  pull the dependency `project-alpha`, and press it  you can find its `pom.xml` in idea, if there no `project-alpha`  `pom.xml` or `dependency` is invaild  ,it must be some problem ,when you try install dependency locally ,you can use the `maven` which  provided by `idea`  and run  with   `mvn install -DskipTests=true`;

- other way to slove invaild dependecy

if through  install project locally by maven is invaild , beside this way  ,that you can try to  add extra  `module` in idea .
you can click in order  as below in  idea  -> `File` -> `New` -> `module`

Comment: The dependency jar (project-alpha-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) is pulled and is a part of message service jar, but still cannot access the ResponseHeader class

Comment: what is your jdk version? if you use jdk abovejdk9+， ```module-info``` may be  the cause of problem ,   if you had no  ```module-info ```  in  ``` project-alpha-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar``` ,try to remove the ```module-info```which  ```java file ```  in your consumer service . and  if you want learn more  about  ```module-info```  , refer to this [article](https://www.oracle.com/de/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), in general  , a compact code snippet is below```module ifx.fxClient {
    requires spring.boot;

}```

Comment: Just to inform, same project I have open in STS4 then I can able to import the class and can access the methods as well. Not sure why IntelliJ is not able to do import the class.